# The <title> tags can only contain a call to wp_title(). Use the wp_title filter to modify the output

Tags: wp-title

I am submitting my theme to WordPress.org. To make it compatible with WordPress 4.1 and greater, I replaced `wptitle()` tag with `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' )` but now the error has changed to following:

```
REQUIRED: The <title> tags can only contain a call to wp_title(). Use the wp_title filter to modify the output
```

Here is a snippet from my header code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title><?php add_theme_support( 'title-tag' ); ?></title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

I have read [this](https://github.com/Otto42/theme-check/issues/10) Github discussion and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794433/wp-head-add-a-second-title-tag) StackOverflow question to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

`add_theme_support( 'title-tag' )` doesn't belong in your header template. It belongs in your `functions.php` file. Usually, it's best to wrap it in it's own function and hook it to `after_setup_theme` in order to allow plugins and child themes to override it later if they need to. So...

```
function wpse_add_title_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}
add_action ( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_add_title_support' );
```

Once you have declared title support, you can remove the `<title>` tag from `header.php` altogether and WP will handle putting it in.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way:

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

and write this into after_setup_theme function  `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );`